# TSQL statements returning different values based on the order the variables are listed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

The below TSQL statements are returning different values based on the order of @Size and @Value.The first statement returns 1687.500000 but the second one 1687.600000. 
I am guessing it's because of some rounding but I can't really figure out myself. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
DECLARE @Amount DECIMAL(20,4) = 2,
@PriceDiff DECIMAL(25,10) = 0.421875,
@Size DECIMAL(16,4)= 200000.0000,
@Value DECIMAL(25,15)= 0.010000000000000

SELECT  @Amount * @PriceDiff * @Size * @Value   AS FinalValue 

SELECT  @Amount * @PriceDiff *  @Value * @Size   AS FinalValue
```

[From Management studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGMnV.png)

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are experiencing the rounding error is due to the way that SQL Server determines the result of multiplication on a Decimal type's precicion and scale. [see here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476(v=sql.110).aspx)

Also, SQL Server's order of operation for the same/equal-precedence operators is [LTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql) .

Given that the first step is to multiple @Amount * @PriceDiff. According to that link the precision and scale would be:

```
 precision = 20 + 25 + 1 = 46
 scale = 4 + 10 = 14
 resulting data type = Decimal(46, 14)
```

This result is over the max allowed precision for a Decimal so things get a little sticky. At the bottom of that link you will  see:

> - The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.

[Reading up on this further](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/03/29/multiplication-and-division-with-numerics/) you'll find that instead of just lopping off all of the decimal places to make a `Decimal(38,0)` or allowing all precision to decimal with a `Decimal(38,38)` SQL server makes a big fat guess and makes it a `Decimal(38,6)`.

All is well and good though as our result so far is `0.84375` and that fits fine into our new `Decimal(38,6)` container.

You can see now that if we multiply this by your @Size we will still be within the limits of a `Decimal(38,6)` with a result of `168750`. So we are still good even with the Precision and Scale math and the resulting rounding to a scale of 6 that will occur.

However, if we take that `0.84375` result and multiple by it `@Value` we get:

```
 precision = 38 + 25 + 1 = 64
 scale = 6 + 15 = 21
 result = Decimal(64, 21)
```

Which means we are back at forcing it into a Decimal(38,6)... And `0.0084375` doesn't fit, so it's rounded to `0.08438`.